# Are these code snippets equivalent ('set xact_abort on' vs 'try catch rollback')?

Tags: sql-server, xact-abort

I used to use this code snippet within my stored procedure in SQL Server:

```
create procedure proc_name
    --declare variables
as
    set nocount on
    begin transaction
    begin try
        --do something
        commit transaction
    end try begin catch
        rollback transaction
        ;throw
    end catch
go
```

but today I got to know 'set xact_abort on' statement.
Is the following code equivalent to previous one? Are there any differences between them?

```
create procedure proc_name
    --declare variables
as
    set nocount on
    set xact_abort on
    begin transaction
    --do something
    commit transaction
go
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from [MS docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx)

A TRY…CATCH construct catches all execution errors that have a severity higher than 10 that do not close the database connection.

So, try catch does not catch all possible errors. You can use xact_abort on in addition to try catch.

try/catch give you more flexibility, i.e., you are not limited to just a rollback when something is not happy.

Comment: «try catch does not catch all possible errors». And xact_abort rollbacks tran when encounters any error, including warnings with severity level <= 10 ?
«try/catch give you more flexibility» - I knew this, but I don't use this flexibility in my snippet. Still this your remark is useful though.